# need help, twitter post wont show up

Tags: javascript, twitter

can somebody help me with these codings...
this code work at another twitter account, 
but when i try to retrive post from "goelalifest" twitter account, it wont show up.

```
<div id="twitter_update_list"></div>
<script src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/bingkwo.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

the problem is when i change the account into "goelalifest", it wont show, but if i replace "bingkwo" with another twitter acc, it works.

can somebody help me to fix it so i can retrieve goelalifest post with this code.
thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an error in twitters response. Because the two last updates by the user goelalifest are retweets and the method "statuses/user_timeline" you are using is set to strip out retweets if calling in xml or json format the two first responses are empty. This is a bug and should be fixed by twitter.

A temporary fix would be to set the count parameter to three, so that the response would contain one update.
So change

```
<script src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/bingkwo.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/goelalifest.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=3" type="text/javascript"></script>
```